# Proving a claim $|c_n e^{in\theta}| = |c_n|$

Tags: fourier-series, absolute-value

I'm studying about Fourier series from a book called "Fourier series and its applications" by Folland and on page 40, the author makes the claim that:

$$|c_n e^{in\theta}| = |c_n|,$$

where $n$ is an index ranging from $0$ to $\infty$, $i$ is the imaginary number, $\theta$ is an angle and $c_n$ is defined as:

$$c_n = \frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\pi}^\pi f(\phi)e^{-in\phi}\:d\phi,$$

where $f(\phi)$ is a piecewise-smooth $2\pi$-periodic function. How to show that $|c_n e^{in\theta}| = |c_n|$? I will provide additional information from the book if required.

Comment: It follows from $\lvert e^{in\theta}\rvert = 1$. Does that one look familiar?

Comment: $|zw| = |z||w|$ for all $z,w \in \mathbb{C}$

Comment: +1 Aah, but of course...thnx x) Missed that

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This has nothing to do with Fourier series, it is just a simple fact about the modulus of complex numbers.

Given two complex numbers $z$ and $w$ we have $|zw| = |z||w|$, so $|c_ne^{in\theta}| = |c_n||e^{in\theta}|$. Furthermore, we have $|e^{in\theta}| = 1$. This can be seen by applying Euler's rule: $$|e^{in\theta}| = |\cos(n\theta) + i\sin(n\theta)| = \sqrt{\cos^2(n\theta)+\sin^2(n\theta)} = \sqrt{1} = 1.$$

Comment: +1 But of course :) Wasn't careful enough x) Thank you :)